# Subquery returns different values for 2 almost identical queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql, subquery

I'm confused about below queries and their return values. Why it only returns one value when I define **`recipe r`** in subquery, but returns 20 values when I define the **`recipe r`** in the main query? What causes the difference?

First query:

```
SELECT   pizza, ingredient, amount 
FROM     recipe 
WHERE    amount = 
         (      SELECT Max(amount) 
                FROM   recipe r
                WHERE  ingredient=r.ingredient) 
ORDER BY ingredient;

  pizza  | ingredient | amount  
---------+------------+--------  
 seafood | seafood    |    200
```

Second query:

```
SELECT   pizza, ingredient, amount 
FROM     recipe r 
WHERE    amount= 
         (      SELECT max(amount) 
                FROM   recipe 
                WHERE  ingredient=r.ingredient) 
ORDER BY ingredient;

   pizza    | ingredient | amount  
------------+------------+--------   
 napolitana | anchovies  |    100
 special    | bacon      |     25
 cabanossi  | cabanossi  |    150
 siciliano  | capsicum   |     75
 mexicano   | capsicum   |     75
 margarita  | cheese     |    120
 mexicano   | chilli     |     25
 special    | egg        |     25
 garlic     | garlic     |     25
 ham        | ham        |    150
 mushroom   | mushroom   |    100
 napolitana | olives     |     75
 mexicano   | onion      |     75
 vegetarian | peas       |     50
 americano  | pepperoni  |     75
 hawaiian   | pineapple  |    100
 americano  | salami     |    120
 seafood    | seafood    |    200
 mexicano   | spice      |     20
 vegetarian | tomato     |     50
```

Comment: You should also choose which database you are using and tag the question appropriately.  I'm removing the specific database tags and replacing them with just "sql".

Comment: Thank you so much! this is my first time to post question, try to do better next time. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two queries are:

```
select pizza, ingredient, amount
from recipe
where amount = (select max(amount)
                from recipe r
                where ingredient = r.ingredient
               )
order by ingredient;
```

and:

```
select pizza, ingredient, amount
from recipe r
where amount = (select max(amount)
                from recipe
                where ingredient = r.ingredient
                )
order by ingredient;
```

Both of these are phrased as correlated subqueries.  But, the first is not correlated.  In the condition:

```
                where ingredient = r.ingredient
```

Both references to `ingredient` are to the table in the inner query.  So, this is basically a no-op.  More specifically, it is exactly equivalent to `where r.ingredient is not null`.  This inner query returns a single value, the largest value of `amount` in the table.

The second version is correlated, so it returns the largest amount for each ingredient.

It is a good rule to fully qualify all table names.  The query that you want should look like this:

```
select r.pizza, r.ingredient, r.amount
from recipe r
where r.amount = (select max(r2.amount)
                  from recipe r2
                  where r2.ingredient = r.ingredient
                 )
order by r.ingredient;
```